# Python/C++ : Embedding script in Qt/C++ application Error

Tags: python, c++, qt

I am attempting to embed a python script in a Qt/C++ project. In my Qt Project file, I have added the Python Framework and the Python library location.

```
INCLUDEPATH += "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib"
INCLUDEPATH += "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m"
LIBS += -F"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/" -framework python
```

After reading the documentation, I am able to run a simple python script, using PyRun_SimpleFile(). I am now trying to run a script that takes an argument as input from C++ and returns an argument as output.

Using the documentation, I could write the following function :

```
const char *ss = "MainFile";
PyObject* name ;
name  = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(ss);
PyObject* pluginModule = PyImport_ImportModule("MainFile");
Py_DECREF(name);
if (!pluginModule)
{
    PyErr_Print();
    return "Error importing module";
}
PyObject* filterFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pluginModule, "attoMainFunction");
Py_DECREF(pluginModule);
if (!filterFunc)
{
    PyErr_Print();
    return "Error retrieving 'attoMainFunction'";
}
PyObject* args = Py_BuildValue("(s)", s.toStdString().c_str());
if (!args)
{
    PyErr_Print();
    Py_DECREF(filterFunc);
    return "Error building args tuple";
}
PyObject* resultObj = PyObject_CallObject(filterFunc, args);
Py_DECREF(filterFunc);
Py_DECREF(args);
if (!resultObj)
{
    PyErr_Print();
    return "Error invoking 'filterFunc'";
}
const char* resultStr = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(resultObj);
if (!resultStr)
{
    PyErr_Print();
    Py_DECREF(resultObj);
    return "Error converting result to C string";
}
std::string result = resultStr;
Py_DECREF(resultObj);
return result;
```

When I run the above function, I get the following error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault", referenced from:
  MainWindow::pythonTry(QString&) in mainwindow.o
```

Am I missing linking a Python library with the project? Or is there anything wrong with the function I'm calling?

Thanks for your time.